# run all test in production

Tags: apex, trigger, deployment, code-coverage, test-setup

Does using Run all test in Production impacts or triggers anything unusual? Will there be any impact on clicking Run all test. I would like to move some code from Full to prod. in FUll it shows 82% coverage but in Prod it only shows 71%. But before I started my development I did a staging refresh to get a fresh copy of Prod to FULL. I am using the same code since then. So if I run Run all test I guess it should give me right code coverage in prod.

Comment: Are you asking whether tests run differently in Production than in a sandbox?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you run all tests in PROD during a deployment, it will run all tests in PROD including the new tests that are part of the deployment (assuming you check that deployment option).

If your fullcopy sandbox is a recent refresh of PROD and you are now getting 82% coverage in fullcopy AND, you are migrating all of the changed classes and metadata to PROD, then I would expect PROD run all tests to be 82% also.

**Obligatory SFSE note:**
Of course, code coverage by itself is not a good proxy for accurate code versus specifications. Code coverage *per se* without asserts only verifies you aren't throwing exceptions. Best practice: you should have good solid testmethods with asserts.